# access a certain cell in google visualization table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, html-table

I am using `google visualization table` to display some data in a table. And I add a listener to the table to track the user click event.

some codes like this:

```
// Add our selection handler.
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);

// The selection handler.
// Loop through all items in the selection and concatenate
// a single message from all of them.
function selectHandler() {
  var selection = table.getSelection();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    var item = selection[i];
    if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, item.column);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '} = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.row != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, 0);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ', column:none}; value (col 0) = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(0, item.column);
      message += '{row:none, column:' + item.column + '}; value (row 0) = ' + str + '\n';
    }
  }
  if (message == '') {
    message = 'nothing';
  }
  alert('You selected ' + message);
}
```

The problem is that, It seems that the listener can only detect which row it is clicked, but have no idea about the column information. Is someone know how to access a particular cell in `google visualization table` by user click? Or some other js library which are more powerful I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API-based access to the column-index, you must use the DOM.

Add a click-listener to the `<table>` and when it fires detect the column-index by using the index of the `<td>` in the childNodes of the parent `<tr>`

Simple example:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike', {
        v: 10000,
        f: '$10,000'
      },
      true
    ],
    ['Jim', {
        v: 8000,
        f: '$8,000'
      },
      false
    ],
    ['Alice', {
        v: 12500,
        f: '$12,500'
      },
      true
    ],
    ['Bob', {
        v: 7000,
        f: '$7,000'
      },
      true
    ]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    document.querySelector('#table_div tbody').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var cell = e.srcElement || e.target,
        column = null;
      if (table.getSelection().length && cell !== cell.parentNode.firstChild) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cell.parentNode.childNodes.length; ++i) {
          if (cell.parentNode.childNodes[i] === cell) {
            column = i - 1;
            break;
          }

        }

        if (column !== null) {
          var msg = ['column-index is ' + column];
          var selection = table.getSelection();
          //if current row has been selected
          if (/\bgoogle-visualization-table-tr-sel\b/.test(cell.parentNode.className)) {
            msg.push('row-index is ' + selection[selection.length - 1].row);
            msg.push('value of clicked cell is:' + data.getValue(selection[selection.length - 1].row, column));
          } else {
            msg.push('current row is not selected');
          }

          alert(msg.join('\n---------\n'))
        }
      } else {
        alert('no row selected');
      }
    });
  });
  table.draw(data, {
    showRowNumber: true
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['table']}]}"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For `google.visualization.table` you could consider the following approach to access column property (from table cell):

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike', {
          v: 10000,
          f: '$10,000'
      },
        true
      ],
      ['Jim', {
          v: 8000,
          f: '$8,000'
      },
        false
      ],
      ['Alice', {
          v: 12500,
          f: '$12,500'
      },
        true
      ],
      ['Bob', {
          v: 7000,
          f: '$7,000'
      },
        true
      ]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function(){
        selectHandler(table);
    });
    table.draw(data, {
        showRowNumber: false
    });
}



function selectHandler(table) {
  var selection = table.getSelection();
  if(selection.length === 0)
      return;

  var cell = event.target; //get selected cell
 
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Row: " +  selection[0].row + " Column: " +  cell.cellIndex;

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: HI, you never define `event`, then how will `event.target` work? I integrate your codes into mine and it has error: `event is not defined`

Comment: @byteBiter, i guess you are using IE, then try to replace `var cell = event.target;` with `var evt=event||window.event;` and then `var cell = evt.target;`

Comment: Hi, I am using `Firefox` and I just checked that you can not access the standard `event` in `firefox` like that.